# How to setup spring-boot to allow access to the webserver from outside IP addresses

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, webserver

I have been looking into how to setup `tomcat` within `spring-boot` to allow access from outside IP addresses.  Currently I can view the UI from locahost:port but I can not access this from other systems.

```
http://localhost:8081
```

When I am logged into the local computer it works.

```
http://192.168.0.93:8081
```

When I am logged into the local computer and try http://192.168.0.93:8081 it does not work.

I want to access the UI from another computer via its IP address it does not work.

```
http://192.168.0.93:8081
```

When I got to `springs` documentation I found you can add the IP address on which you want tomcat to set the webserver for using server.address.  This should then allow the server to be accessed via this IP address by outside systems.

```
server.port=8082
server.address=192.168.0.93
```

The port works fine if I do not supply the address but when I supply the address and try to run it I run into an issue for binding to that address.  It looks like `spring-boot` has already assigned locahost:8082.

## Question:

How do I correctly setup `spring-boot` to allow tomact to be accessed by outside addresses and recognize its own IP when accessed locally?

Thank you

## Stack Trace:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
  at com.miw.mcb.server.ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.main(ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.java:18)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-25 11:24:30 - Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8081]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8081]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
  at com.miw.mcb.server.ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.main(ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.java:18)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
  ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986)
  ... 20 common frames omitted
2016-05-25 11:24:30 - Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-192.168.0.93-8081"]
2016-05-25 11:24:30 - Stopping service Tomcat
2016-05-25 11:24:30 - The stop() method was called on component [StandardServer[-1]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
2016-05-25 11:24:30 - Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-192.168.0.93-8081"]
2016-05-25 11:24:30 - Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-192.168.0.93-8081"]
2016-05-25 11:24:30 - Application startup failed
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
  at com.miw.mcb.server.ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.main(ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.java:18)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159)
  ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Think you want to read up on CORS - https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/. Also, I believe what you are doing is trying to tell the application to run off the target IP.

Comment: @mugua          I setup CORS for our REST web services following that guide when communicating from one web server to the other.  That works without an issue but it is communicating via localhost:DIFF_PORTS.  The issue I believe is allowing different IP addresses to accessing the UI from another system which I believe is in tomcat.  I thought I read up that if you do not specify the server.address it will bind to 0.0.0.0

Comment: sorry, guess I misunderstood. I thought you were trying to access the application from a remote computer by inputting the remote computer's IP. I think you're correct in that by not specifying an IP, it will default to localhost, but that should still include the local IP of the host machine.

Comment: @mugua          I added some more details to the question

Comment: I doubt that spring-boot has already assigned the address. If it did, I think it would give you a more explicit exception, saying something like "address already in use." If that was the case, you could kill the process or restart the system and try again.
I'd be wondering if it was a network thing at this point and if certain port ranges are blocked. Maybe turn of your firewall if you can and see what happens.
On my own application, I set nothing, and I can access the app by IP or domain name assigned by the network folks.

Comment: @mugua                 I disabled the firewall on CentOS.  I am unable to access it on the local machine even with its IP http://192.168.0.93:8081/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since so many people have viewed this question.  The resolution was to make sure the firewall was configured correctly on the hosting CentOS machine and not set the server address explicitly.

**INCORRECT SETUP**

This **failed** previously with the firewall incorrectly setup

```
server.port=8081
server.address=192.168.0.93
```

Once the firewall is correctly setup **you do not need to specify the server.address just the port**.

**CORRECT SETUP**

```
server.port=8081
```

This allowed me to access the application correctly from other systems using its ip.

```
http://<someip>:<server.port>
http://192.168.0.93:8081
```

Comment: what firewall changes did you make? I am facing similar problem.

Comment: @Harsh          The changes are shown above, did you try those?

Comment: yes I have set server.port and server.address but its not working. I have also opened up the 8080 port still it shows 404 error.

Comment: @Harsh         As mentioned above once I setup the firewall correctly I removed the "server.address" and only used the "server.port" and it worked correctly.

Comment: thanks for your response. Could you please elaborate on firewall setup that you did? I have opened up 8080 port. Do I need to do anything other than that?

Comment: can you share fire wall settings?

Comment: @АлмасАбдразак I no longer have that VM so I am unable to provide it but have you read the comments above and details.

Comment: server.address=0.0.0.0 should work too. It's called the network interface binding...

Comment: This is not the correct answer, you just mentioned set up the firewall correctly but how. The answer below this gives correct solution.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you, you saved me tons!
I wanted to post this in comments, but I don't have enough reputation to reply.

Those of you who want the information regarding firewall changes,

I used firewalld to add my springboot webserver ports in my vm(centos7)

My webserver was using 8080, so I did:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --reload --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp*

sudo systemctl restart firewalld*
```

you need to restart/reload the firewalld to apply the changes.
if you,

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all*
```

you can find `8080/tcp` has been added to ports list

Comment: firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp
worked for me

Answer (score 2):

**This can be done easily by using `ufw`**

To view currently opened ports enter: `sudo ufw status numbered` (Take a screenshot just for safety)

To open port enter: `sudo ufw allow 8080` (8080 or any port you want)

To remove port enter: `sudo ufw delete {number}`

Remember to double check the number with `sudo ufw status numbered` before you delete it.

:-)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by the firewall you need to open the port. I am using ubuntu. This command opened the port for me. My application uses port 8000 so I used the command  below to open the port

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp
```

Then use the command to restart the firewall service

```
sudo systemctl restart firewalld
```

Also check if you have set the server.servlet.context-path in the springboot application to know the correct endpoint.If not go directly to the port