# start spring boot app installed in a server from another machine

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I installed my spring boot application in another server (linux machine) with the following run jar :

> java -jar myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
>   --spring.config.location=file:/opt/myapp/conf/application.yml

where in my application.yml , i defined the port 8081 which is available, with a context root myApp.

The start of the jar is going well, the DB connected, the app started with the profile dev, in port 8081 and with context myApp properly.

But when i tried to connect from other machine http://serverIP:8081/myApp , the browser sham me ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and no adress exist with this name.

i tried to run the app in my machine and i can access with localhost.

I don't know what is the problem, maybe i'm missing somthing.

I also verified the port and it's open, the ping with ip server was responding also.

Maybe there are other conf that i missed ?

UPDATE:

i followed this link  s[tackoverflow.com/questions/29885274/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885274/tomcat-server-not-working-externally) , with the telnet serverIP 8081 told me no connection, so as the link explain that tomcat is not correctly connected to the ip chossen, in application.xml i added server.adress = serverIP, and the same problem shown

Comment: Is the host reachable from the other machine? Same network, open port...

Comment: yes , there is an other app running in Jboss server in the port 8080 and i can reach it

Comment: i tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885274/tomcat-server-not-working-externally , with the telnet serverIP 8081 told me no connection, so as the link explain that tomcat is not correctly connected to the ip chossen, in application.xml i added server.adress = serverIP, and the same problem shown

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445626/how-to-setup-spring-boot-to-allow-access-to-the-webserver-from-outside-ip-addres

Comment: Maybe a firewall?

Comment: i really don't know, how can i be sur it is related to firewall? i tried the telnet cmd and it doesn't respond, but with the other app in Jboss with 8080 respond

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157652/discussion-between-hector-and-selma).