# Connect to localhost rest api from android mobile device

Tags: android, android-studio, localhost

I have developed a rest api using spring boot in java and it is running on port 8082 on my laptop.

Next I created a android application to consume data from my rest api.
I tested this and it is working fine when I am using android emulator.

But I need it to run it on my android mobile device. How to do so?

I have searched it and this is asked multiple times, but none seem to work for me.

**What I have tried**
I tried connecting to my laptop browser via my laptop Ip and port in android code

**Using same wifi network for both devices**

```
//192.xxx.xx.xx:8082

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.xxx.xx.1:8082")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

**Result**
The app runs, but after about 10 seconds gives connection timeout error and if I use "http://localhost:8082/company/employees" url then displays nothing.

Comment: Are you able to access http://192.xxx.xx.1:8082 in Chrome in mobile device?

Comment: No, I tried it, there also it gives connection timeout error.

Comment: Means you can not access your server outside of your laptop. You need to fix that first.

Comment: Can you give me an idea, what I might try to achieve that.

Comment: I have no idea about spring Boot. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445626/how-to-setup-spring-boot-to-allow-access-to-the-webserver-from-outside-ip-addres

Comment: Try the url in a browser on your Android device.

Comment: Switch off the firewall of your laptop during tests.

Comment: Try the url from another pc in the same network.

Comment: If it runs on the emulator then the only thing you have to change is ip address.

Comment: Issue was with IP Address, changing it, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue:-

1. No need to change any firewall settings
2. Connect the mobile device and api running machine via the same network.
3. Use cmd-->ipconfig on windows to check ip address of api code running machine and "**Wireless Lan Adapter Wi-Fi**" (IPv6) worked for me.
4. Mention full url when connecting via retrofit.

   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
   .baseUrl("http://192.168.xx.xxx:8082/hco/")
   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
   .build();